# error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database in my model class

Tags: java, android-room

I am developing a new application but I am getting the following error in my code:

> Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can
>   consider adding a type converter for it.

I have tried all possible solutions from stackoverflow but did not work.

below my Article.java model class

```
@Entity(
        tableName = "article",
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(
                entity = Source.class,
                parentColumns = "id",
                childColumns = "source"
        ))

public class Article {
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("source")
    @NonNull
    @Expose

    @ColumnInfo(name ="source")
    private Source source;

    public Source getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(Source source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    @SerializedName("author")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "author")
    private String author;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "url")
    private String url;
    @SerializedName("urlToImage")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "urlToImage")
    private String urlToImage;

    @SerializedName("publishedAt")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "publishedAt")
    private String publishedAt;
    @SerializedName("content")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "content")
    private String content;





    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrlToImage() {
        return urlToImage;
    }

    public void setUrlToImage(String urlToImage) {
        this.urlToImage = urlToImage;
    }

    public String getPublishedAt() {
        return publishedAt;
    }

    public void setPublishedAt(String publishedAt) {
        this.publishedAt = publishedAt;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

below Source.java

below Dao class

```
@Dao
public interface SportNewsDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM article")
    List<Article> getArticles();

    @Insert
    void insertAll(Article... article);
    @Delete
    void delete(Article article);

    @Update
    void update(Article article);

}
```

below Database class

```
@Database(entities = {Article.class,Source.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public  abstract class SportNewsDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
  public  abstract SportNewsDao sportNewsDao();
}

below SourceTypeConverter.java
public class  SourceTypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static Source ConvertSource(Source source){
        return source ==   null ? null : new Source(source);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In order to use your `SourceTypeCoverter` you need to add the following annotation to your `SportNewsDatabase` class

```java
@TypeConverters(SourceTypeConverter.class)
```

Also, your SourceTypeConverter may be missing a method. You need a method to convert your Object to some form of primitive and then from the primitive back to your Object. Something like this

```java
public class  SourceTypeConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    public static String ConvertSource(Source source){
        return source == null ? null : source.toString();
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Source ConvertSource(String source){
        return source == null ? null : new Source(source);
    }
}
```

You can read more about this here, [Referencing Complex data using room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data)

Keep in mind using toString() will most likely not work for this. you may need to use something like Gson to convert your object to a string and back.

If that doesn't work, you can always try `@embedded`. [Android Room Embedded](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Embedded)

Answer (score 0):

For Room to find `SourceTypeConverter` you have to register it by annotating your database, Dao or entity with:

```java
@TypeConverters(SourceTypeConverter.class)
```